# Showing the following inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, inequality, partial-derivative

I have the following function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$f(x,y)=\sin((x^2-y^2)\exp(-(x^2+y^2)))$

What I already have:

The partial derivatives are:

$\frac{df}{dx}(x,y)=2xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}[1-x^2+y^2]\cos(e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(x^2-y^2))$
$\frac{df}{dy}(x,y)=-2ye^{-(x^2+y^2)}[1+x^2-y^2]\cos(e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(x^2-y^2))$

With that the function f has the following stationary points:
$P_0(0,0), P_1(0,1), P_2(0,-1), P_3(1,0), P_4(-1,0)$

I need the show the following "Inequality chain":

$|(x^2-y^2)\exp(-(x^2-y^2))|\le(x^2+y^2)\exp(-(x^2-y^2))\le\max_{t\ge  0}{\{te^{-t}\}}\le \frac{1}{e}<\frac{\pi}{2}$

and if the function has more stationry points.

I don't really know how to do that so help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your "Inequality Chain, should it read :  $ e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$?

If yes, the first part of the inequality is easy, and taking $t:=(x^2+y^2)$ the second follows directly, because of the positivity of $y^2$ and $x^2$

$$|(x^2-y^2)|\leq max{\{x^2,y^2\}}\leq x^2+y^2$$
Then using $t$ as above you get:

$$|(x^2-y^2)|e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\leq max{\{x^2,y^2)\}}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\leq (x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\leq sup_{t\geq0}te^{-t}$$

Comment: Hi, yes it should read $e^{−(x^2+y^2)}$ :)

Comment: The last inequalities should be no problem now.